# Angular material - autocomplete mat-error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I'm using [angular](https://angular.io/) 6 with [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) 6.4.2 and I'm not able to show the error properly on an autocomplete.

I've created a stackblitz to show you the behavior, here's the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-faykhk-jnh35k)

My goal, is to show an error on an autocomplete stylized, as expected.

All the help is very welcomed :)

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
Marcelo

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue i used a work around with hint unfortunately

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="form.get('x').hasError('error')" i18n><span class="mat-error">Please choose a X</span></mat-hint>
```

Comment: nice workaround. Not ideal but at least we can put an error under the field. Any luck in colouring the auto-complete red?

Answer (score 0):

this one works great for me:

( i use it to show dynamic error on mat-autocomplete form field at placeholder spot.

if no error - placeholder stay as should)

on your HTML:

```
[placeholder]="isPlaceHolderShowError('myFormControlName')"
```

on your TS:

```
isPlaceHolderShowError(myFormControlName) {
if (this.form.controls[myFormControlName].invalid && this.form.controls[myFormControlName].touched) {
  return 'this is my error text'
}
return 'this is the initial placehloder'
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Your input was never in error state thus error was not displayed. Fixed example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-faykhk-f9y3zc?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html

I just added `required` validator to force error state. If you want to apply some custom rules - write custom validator.

Comment: Hi Antoniossss, thank you ofr your answer. I forgot to add the FormArray part to the code, I've just updated the stackblizt link. Can you please take a look at it ?